# How to remove BOM from the reponse of apache web server?

Tags: php, apache, byte-order-mark

My php code is here:

```
$filename = '/tmp/tech.dat';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
}
```

The size of original file (/tmp/tech.dat) is 40 bytes but the response is 43 bytes.

I've checked the response with WinHex but I could see the 3 bytes of BOM (EF BB BF) in front of the file.

How can I remove the BOM from the server?

I am using Ubuntu as the web server.

Comment: Your PHP script file itself might have this BOM at its beginning. However, there's not enough information in your question to be sure about this. What, for instance, are the headers saying in your browser developer tools?

Comment: How can I remove the BOM in that php file? The PHP script file is like as above. so simple.

Comment: Have you looked in your headers? Use your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) for that. Do you see the headers you created? What length is reported there? If there is a BOM at the beginning of your script file then it has been put there by your editor. Which editor are you using? Does it have an option to save files without a BOM?